# How not to insert date to SQL database if the DateTimePicker is empty

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a table called `LeaveTable` in my SQL Server database and I have the following columns: `ID`, `LeaveType`, `LFrom`, `LTo`, `ReturnDate`. I set the format for the `ReturnDate` as `Custom` and I put a space in `CustomFormat`, so when I open the form the `ReturnDate` is empty.

The problem is when I insert the `Leave` details without entering `ReturnDate` it is inserting today's date in `ReturnDate` field even if it is empty and I don't want that because the employee didn't return yet.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: please Provide Table Structure

Comment: Sounds like the column ReturnDate has a DEFAULT value.

Comment: Can you show us the code which is inserting record to the table?

Comment: The ID is int , LeaveType nvarchar and the rest are date. And there is no default value for the column ReturnDate.

Comment: Here is my code:
`Try
            con = New SqlConnection(cs)
            con.Open()
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO LeaveTable (EmpNo, LFrom, LTo,ReturnDate) VALUES (@EmpNo,@LFrom,@LTo,@ReturnDate)", con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpNo", txt_EmpNo.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LFrom", dtp_From.Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LTo", dtp_To.Value)                
                cmd.ExecuteReader()
                con.Close()`

Comment: Please _do not_ put code in comments!  _Edit_ your question instead and place the code there, where it belongs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure allow nulls is true for the ReturnDate column.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = DBNull.Value
```

Don't use ExecuteReader for an Insert. Use:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much Mary. one more question why to use cmd.ExcuteNonQuery and not ExcuteReader?

Comment: I guess SQL Server is smart enough to figure it out anyway but for Insert, Update and Delete the ExecuteNonQuery should return rows affected. ExecuteReader is normally used for Select commands returning data.